# Convert long to string following template

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I have a number that has to be converted to a String in a specific format, following a template.

The template is xxx.xxx.xxx-xx. For example, if the number is 94322467, it should be converted to 000.943.224-67.

What is the correct way to do this in Java?

#### EDIT

What I ended up using as my code was a mix of both @biziclop and @style answers.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
formatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('-');
formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("000000,000.00", formatSymbols);
String cpfString = myFormatter.format(longNumber / 100.0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is the way to go.

Although if your number will always be fixed length (that is, padded with zeroes if it's shorter), it's probably best to use `DecimalFormat` to format the plain number (`00000000000` is the pattern in your case) and insert the separators to the known fixed positions manually.

Unfortunately `DecimalFormat` won't handle arbitrary digit groupings, so you'll have to manually insert the separator characters.

If your number isn't even guaranteed to be of fixed length, you'll have to write the formatter from scratch.

Comment: `DecimalFormat("000.000.000-00")` and `DecimalFormat("###.###.###-##")` Both throw the error `Multiple decimal separators in pattern`. How would I format it for what I want?

Comment: Is there no automatic way to do this in java? It seems to be such a common problem.

Comment: Displaying numbers in a regular grouping is a common problem, DecimalFormat supports that. I doubt though that using multiple grouping separators and different group lengths is a common problem. Plus it can be dealt with manually fairly easily, as @style's answer shows.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
long x = 123456789;
String s = String.format("%,d-%02d", x / 100, x % 100);
String out = ("000.000.000-00" + s.replace(",", ".")).substring(s.length());
System.out.println(out);
```

This results with what you want:

```
   001.234.567-89
```

Comment: For `1000000` it gives me `0000010.000-00`, but I need `000.0010.000-00`. Besides that, I need it to always use `.` and not `,`.

Comment: Does format use locale to set thousands separator? Because if it does this might not work for someone in Poland (I thin they use spaces as thousand separators). I made an answer using yours and @biziclop one together. Thanks